# Swift UIView Animation block increment error

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView Animation block that I want to run on paragraphs in an array.

```
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.2, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                var frame = self.textViewForPlayer.frame
                frame.origin.y += 20
                self.textViewForPlayer.frame = frame
                }, completion: { finished in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                        var frame = self.textViewForPlayer.frame
                        frame.origin.y -= 80
                        self.textViewForPlayer.frame = frame
                        }, completion: { finished in
                        })
                    }
            )

            textViewForPlayer = paragraphs[++currentParagraph]
```

Strange thing is - the first block (first animation before completion) runs the animation on the first paragraph, but the chained animation in the first completion block runs on the second paragraph (somehow the "paragraphs[++currentParagraph]" is executing in between the two blocks of animation.

Not sure how this is happening, the increment code is after the animation itself, so it seems bizarre or maybe even a bug that causes it to execute in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the animations and completion block are called at a latter time, but animateWithDuration returns immediately.
Everything outside the scope of the blocks will run without respect to the delay of the animation or the animation being finished. 
Consider putting the incrementation inside your last finished block. This should increment the number at the end of both animations.

```
...,completion: { finished in
              textViewForPlayer = paragraphs[++currentParagraph]
             })
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. so i guess the completion block is called at some undefined point in the future..

Comment: Basically after the animation has finished. This is in the future because the animation can have a certain duration and delay